# Order of UIViewController events in the iOS simulator?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uikit, ios-simulator

Is the follwing a bug or a feature?

My test app has one root `UIViewController`. It implements `viewDidAppear:` and `willRotateToDeviceOrientation:`

Now it happens that the iOS simulator is already running and is set to **landscape**.
If I put breakpoints, I can clearly see that `viewDidAppear:` is called before `willRotateToDeviceOrientation:`

The consequence of this is that in `viewDidAppear:` the width and height of the view are still incorrect: width = 768, height = 1024.
Only after `willRotateToDeviceOrientation:` they are correct.

If I quit the simulator and run the app, the simulator will start in portrait. Only `viewDidAppear:` will be triggered and the width = 768, the height = 1024 - as expected.

Why is the `willRotateToDeviceOrientation:` called at all? The device is already in landscape and it knows that because it does not trigger a rotation animation at all.

Am I supposed to reconfigure my views' dimensions in `willRotateToDeviceOrientation:`?